# Is it possible to display horizontal scroll bar in DataGrid which have no row(s)?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

I would like to allow users to scroll a `DataGrid` horizontally even if there are no row(s) in the `DataGrid`. Just to allow them to find out all the columns that exists in `DataGrid`. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is without redefining the template. I was able to get the scrollbar to show up (by accessing it directly) but not to actually scroll. I ended up going with the suggestion in a similar post of adding a dummy row and setting the row height to 0 when there are no rows. It's ugly, but it works.

```
if (dtEnrollments.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    dtEnrollments.Rows.Add(dtEnrollments.NewRow());
    dgClassRoster.RowHeight = 0;
}
else
    dgRoster.RowHeight = defaultRowHeight;

dgRoster.ItemsSource = dtEnrollments.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the horizontal scrollbar with `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` or if that fails you can disable scrolling inside `DataGrid` and wrap it into a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` this doesn't work unless you have rows. I can't use ScrollViewer because of performance hit it causes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `DataGrid` in a `ScrollViewer`, with the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` forced to `Visible`, and add the following property to the `DataGrid` :

```
<DataGrid.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>                        
         <ItemsPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>

</DataGrid.Template>
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I can't use ScrollViewer because of performance hit it causes

Comment: Ouch. The only (painful) way out I'd suggest is to completely re-template DataGrid, because the default style has a ScrollViewer embedded

Comment: Default one's performance hit is nothing as compared to a ScrollViewer wrapper over the DataGrid. Try out yourself. In case of large number of rows there is a huge performance difference between DataGrid inside ScrollViewer and one without it

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the `MaxWidth` of the `DataGrid` to the `ActualWidth` of the parent element (`Control/Window/Grid`/etc.).

Comment: Problem is that the parent control i.e. a Grid covers the complete screen but the DataGrid is larger than that. It cannot be contained inside its parent. It must have horizontal scroll for completely display itself

Comment: I believe that if you set a MaxWidth on the DataGrid it should automatically scroll. You can test this by setting it to some value.